# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable - Train regression keras model with custom loss function and run_eagerly=True

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I create a dummy regression keras model to check my custom loss before giving it to an actual model.
For now i only want this custom loss function to run. I want to know where and why i'm wrong and how to fix my custom loss.
I appreciate any help and thank you very much in advance.

Keras version: 2.2.4
Tensorflow version: 2.2
Python version: 3.7

[UPDATED_1] - I removed all numpy functions inside my loss function but still got the same error.
This is my code after [UPDATED_1]:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras.backend as K
import subprocess
#tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_shape = K.get_value(K.shape(y_true)[0])
    for i in range(y_true_shape):
        f = open('y_pred.txt', 'w')
        y_pred_temp = K.get_value(y_pred[i])
        f.write(str(y_pred_temp))
        f.close()
        f = open('y_true.txt', 'w')
        y_true_temp = K.get_value(y_true[i])
        f.write(str(y_true_temp))
        f.close()
        #temp = subprocess.call()# calls an outside program to read both y_true.txt and y_pred.txt 
        #and writes a loss value after being calculated into a txt file
        #bcs i'm testing this custom loss funtion so i just create a dummy txt file named "lossVals.txt" 
        #and its content is "1234"
        f = open('lossVals.txt', 'r')
        lossVal_data = f.read()
        f.close()
        lossVal_temp = K.variable((tf.strings.to_number(lossVal_data),))
        if i == 0:
            loss = lossVal_temp
        else:
            loss = K.concatenate((loss, lossVal_temp), axis=0)
    return loss
x_train = np.random.rand(1000, 199)
y_train = np.random.rand(1000, 199)
x_test = np.random.rand(200, 199)
y_test = np.random.rand(200, 199)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(199,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(199, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer='adam', run_eagerly=True)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1)
```

and this is the error logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-84-ebd97e65f38d>", line 1, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 572, in train_function
    self.train_step, args=(data,))

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 951, in run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 2290, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 2649, in _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 282, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 541, in train_step
    self.trainable_variables)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1804, in _minimize
    trainable_variables))

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 521, in _aggregate_gradients
    filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)

  File "C:\Users\Deut\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 1219, in _filter_grads
    ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'].
```

Comment: You cannot use numpy functions inside a keras loss, they can only be implemented using keras backend functions, as else the gradient cannot be propagated through your loss and you get these errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found all numpy functions and replaced with keras backend function and tensorflow funtion that return output as tensor but still got the same error. Please continue to help me.